# TYPE argument in Mat

Tags: image, opencv

I have a color image and I want to assign the every pixel with only gray value (In the  HSV system) into another Matrix to create a gray image. 
 So I create a Matrix by  **V.create(image.rows,image.cols,CV_8UC1)**, then I have a gray image.  But I thought what will happen when I replace that with **V.create(image.rows,image.cols,CV_8UC3)**. I thought it will be the same because I assign value into the third Channel only, although it is 8UC3.  But What I got is a gray image whose size is  full height but with only 1/3 width. 2/3 left are all blank. I am curious about why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can investigate how matrixes and images are stored inside the memory in this [documentation page](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html). It explains pretty well how pixels are stored under the hood and how they can be read.